# Headless openvpn client on windows?

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, console, headless

I'm looking for a client that can be run as an openvpn client but either headless or only in console. Reason being that I want to wrap a GUI application around it. I know that OpenVPN has the management tool that you can use telnet to access, but I don't want any sort of front end for my client except what I'm providing myself.

I've been looking around online and I can't seem to find any sort of starting point to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Found the actual openvpn client binary and ran it via CLI, turns out you can just run `openvpn.exe --config file` and then monitor the STDOUT of the process.